# throw new Error('Cyclic dependency' + nodeRep)

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have used lot of charts in my application and I want to handle all charts colors from the vuex store how it can possible. I have used below code to make this.

**store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

// modules
import settings from './modules/settings';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        settings
    }
})
```

**chart-config.js**

```
/**
* Change all chart colors
*/
import { store } from "../store/store";

const { primary, warning, error, info, success } = store.getters.chartColors;

export const ChartConfig = {
   color: {
      'primary': primary,
      'warning': warning,
      'danger': error,
      'success': success,
      'info': info,
      'white': '#fff',
      'lightGrey': '#E8ECEE'
   },
   lineChartAxesColor: '#E9ECEF',
   legendFontColor: '#AAAEB3', // only works on react chart js 2
   chartGridColor: '#EAEAEA',
   axesColor: '#657786',
   shadowColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)'
}
```

Folder structure:

```
src
 -components
 -constants
   --chart-config.js
 -store
   --store.js
 -views
 App.vue
 main.js
```

I have got this type of error whenever I try to run npm run dev command

```
95% emitting HtmlWebpackPlugin/media/iron/631dbce0-858c-4a8c-bef4- 
a01a6a92507f/shubham/work/dev/vue/myapp/node_modules/toposort/index.js:35 
throw new Error('Cyclic dependency' + nodeRep)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2018-07-31**

Some days ago, I had the same problem when working with a vue app created with `@vue/cli` (Vue CLI 3). But [they fixed it](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1669) recently.

**Old Answer**

The solution for me was to create [`vue.config.js`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html) in the project root directory (next to `package.json`) that [resets `chunksSortMode` of the package `html-webpack-plugin`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51225345/10134040):

*vue.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config
      .plugin('html')
      .tap(args => {
        args[0].chunksSortMode = 'none'

        return args
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: Got error "chunksSortMode of undefined" in vue pages option! What to do on this!!?args are empty