# Cyclic dependency with more than one Angular route

Tags: angular, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I am working on an Angular 6.0.7 application with Webpack 4.15.1. The application runs great when using the webpack-dev-server, but once I try to build it using production mode, it fails at the HtmlWebpackPlugin emitting stage.

It must have something to do with HtmlWebpackPlugin because if I remove the plugin then the javascript files generate without a problem. It may have to do with the number of generated chunks.

This did not happen until I added two new routes to my application. Once I remove *any two* routes, the application compiles fine. Here is the error:

```
> webpack --config webpack/webpack.production.config.js --progress

clean-webpack-plugin: C:\example\WiFi-Setup\bin has been removed.
 95% emitting HtmlWebpackPluginUnhandled rejection Error: Cyclic dependency
    at visit (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\node_modules\toposort\index.js:35:13)
    at visit (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\node_modules\toposort\index.js:53:9)
    at visit (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\node_modules\toposort\index.js:53:9)
    at Function.toposort [as array] (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\node_modules\toposort\index.js:22:22)
    at Object.module.exports.dependency (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\lib\chunksorter.js:50:35)
    at HtmlWebpackPlugin.sortChunks (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\index.js:364:35)
    at C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\html-webpack-plugin\index.js:113:21
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:12:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:35:21)
    at Compiler.emitAssets (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:364:19)
    at onCompiled (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:231:9)
    at hooks.afterCompile.callAsync.err (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:553:14)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:35:21)
    at compilation.seal.err (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:550:30)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:35:21)
    at hooks.optimizeAssets.callAsync.err (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1283:35)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:35:21)
    at hooks.optimizeChunkAssets.callAsync.err (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1274:32)
    at _err0 (eval at create (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:282:11
    at step (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin\dist\uglify\index.js:90:11)
    at done (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin\dist\uglify\index.js:99:22)
    at tryCatcher (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
    at Promise._fulfill (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:638:18)
    at Promise._resolveCallback (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:432:57)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:524:17)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\example\WiFi-Setup\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
```

I tried to create a small runnable example but could not replicate the issue. Here is the repository [when it compiles](https://github.com/Gizmode-Innovations/WiFi-Setup/tree/e169d0107cd88a4f0952d2e7f0cfa9ff68607280) and [when it does not](https://github.com/Gizmode-Innovations/WiFi-Setup/tree/e824347d5c30c0ed0d16abb9ccd3afa424383f2a). The relevant commit after which this issue appeared is found [here](https://github.com/Gizmode-Innovations/WiFi-Setup/commit/e824347d5c30c0ed0d16abb9ccd3afa424383f2a).

Thanks for any suggestions. I've been debugging this all day.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I came across the same issue some days ago. I found 3 possible fixes.

1. Reset `chunksSortMode`

   ```
   plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            chunksSortMode: 'none'
        })
    ]
   ```
2. Update `html-webpack-plugin`

- Update `html-webpack-plugin` to v4.0.0 or newer because `toposort` [was removed in  v4.0.0](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/981#issuecomment-399345841). In addition, you can check that in the [dependencies for v4.0.0](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/v4.0.0/package.json)

3. Fix circular dependencies

- Install [circular-dependency-plugin](https://github.com/aackerman/circular-dependency-plugin)
- Run webpack without `html-webpack-plugin`
- Try to fix if possible, the circular dependencies that the plugin reports

Also I realised that the latest version of [mocha-webpack](https://github.com/zinserjan/mocha-webpack) has the same issue due to `toposort` in that case the only solution for me was to downgrade `webpack@3`

Comment: Alpha version of `html-webpack-plugin` works fine. I'll just go with my solution until it's stable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was apparently caused by html-webpack-plugin getting into some kind of loop with `chunksSortMode: 'dependency'`, so instead I sorted manually as so:

```
chunks: ['polyfills', 'vendor', 'main'],
chunksSortMode: 'manual'
```